# Subdomain install no longer working after domain switch

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, cpanel, whm

I have about five different subdomains on my host that are all working fine with wordpress installed.

I recently switched from Godaddy to Namecheap and bought a new domain name.

I changed the domain on my WHM Server which was all fine with my current sites.

The problem I have is when adding a new subdomain and installing Wordpress the site breaks because of DNS issues.

The Wordpress auto install is also weird as it doesn't detect the root like it used to, it puts the sub domain name into a folder above public_html.

So old subdomains are working fine but adding a new subdomain brings dns errors with wordpress installed.

Any ideas please, I've spent a solid five hours on this already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem myself, for anyone with a similar issue. I even went through Hostgator support who couldn't figure out the problem.

Logged into WHM > DNS Functions > Edit DNS Zone

The sub domain in question was not named correctly, it was named as the directory name instead of the full url.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you correctly, you...

1. Created an account and bought a new domain on Namecheap
2. In Namecheap's WHM (Webhost Manager), you changed the domain to the one you had with GoDaddy.
3. When you create a new subdomain in Namecheap's WHM, it's not resolving the subdomain

So based on the above assumptions, it sounds like your domain is still with GoDaddy, and it's still pointing to GoDaddy's name servers. So if you add a new subdomain in Namecheap, it won't do anything, because Namecheap doesn't have control of the DNS. And for that matter, I think your subdomains would still be pointing to GoDaddy's servers.

Again, assuming I followed your description correctly, I'd recommend you migrate your old domain to Namecheap since, I'd assume, you're going to close your GoDaddy account at some point. If you need to urgently create a subdomain, you would need to do that on GoDaddy's end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi pbulecio, thanks for your response. No sorry seems I wasn't very clear.

Godaddy is completely out of the picture now, my domain is with Namecheap and my hosting is with Hostgator with a reseller package.

When I was with Godaddy I created several subdomains, no problems. Then I switched to namecheap domain and edited the domain name within my hosting at hostgator with a new url. Still no problems.

Today I wanted to create a new sub domain for a new project and now I have issues with DNS but my previous sub domains still work fine. Only having issues with newly created sub domains.

Comment: Ok, so Namecheap is your registrar, are you pointing to Namecheap's name servers, or Hostgator's name servers. Also, when you say you create a new subdomain, are you doing that within Hostgagor?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with name servers since all my other subdomains work for about two months now, it's just when creating new ones it breaks. It's just really weird. I create sub domains on the hostgator Cpanel.